# how to reformat date in txt file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a long txt file, t1.txt. For instance I have the following text:

```
"2019-03-11T12:20:22.330Z"
plenty of text ...
"2019-03-11T12:20:43.082Z"
plenty of text ...
```

I would like to reformat the date stamp to resemble something like

```
Day of the week
time (as in 13.48 for example)
plenty of text ...
```

Is this at all possible to do in bash?

Comment: Not in pure bash, but you can call out to `date` to re-format the timestamp. Your output time, should that be in UTC timezone or your local timezone?

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/^"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.[0-9]+Z"$/
    Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")->strftime("%A\n%H:%M")
/e' -- t1.txt
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `-M` uses a module, [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) is a core module that handles basic time parsing and formatting
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is a substitution similar to sed
- `/e` modifier in substitution interprets the REPLACEMENT part as code and runs it
- `strptime` parses time, the format details can be found in `man strptime`
- `strftime` formats the time, where `%A` is the full day name, `\n` is the newline, `%H` stands for hours and `%M` for minutes